# CAEmitterLayer - kCAEmitterLayerRectangle render mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, caemitterlayer

I want to make particles inside the rectangle.

What is wrong in this code? It is emitted from only the emitter position, not, random position in rectangle.

```
fireEmitter = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
[self.view.layer fireEmitter];
fireEmitter.emitterPosition = self.view.center;
fireEmitter.emitterSize =CGSizeMake(100, 100);
fireEmitter.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerRectangle;
fireEmitter.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fire, nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kCAEmitterLayerRectangle` is not a valid value for [`renderMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Emitter_Modes). Instead you should use one of these values

```
kCAEmitterLayerUnordered
kCAEmitterLayerOldestFirst
kCAEmitterLayerOldestLast
kCAEmitterLayerBackToFront
kCAEmitterLayerAdditive
```

The `kCAEmitterLayerRectangle` value should be set as the [`emitterShape`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Emitter_Shape) which defaults to  `kCAEmitterLayerPoint`. That is why you are only emitting from a single point. The valid emitterShapes are:

```
kCAEmitterLayerPoint
kCAEmitterLayerLine
kCAEmitterLayerRectangle
kCAEmitterLayerCuboid
kCAEmitterLayerCircle
kCAEmitterLayerSphere
```

Please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Emitter_Shape) for their meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As David already pointed out the value you are using isn't valid for `renderMode`. It is used in `emitterShape`.
This can be a very frustrating error because Xcode doesn't give you a warning since they are of the same type (`NSString`). Such an error can easily be overlooked even having read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Using a tool like [Particle Playground](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/particle-playground/id600661093) (for UIKit emitters) or [Particle Designer](http://www.71squared.com/en/particledesigner) (for cocos2d emitters) can help a lot since they only allow the values as specified in the documentation.

They both let you configure your emitter layer/cell on your mac. Particle Playground exports the emitter as an objective c class for easy import in your project. Particle Designer exports in an exchange format which can easily be imported into the correct cocos2d emitter classes.

Full disclosure: I wrote Particle Playground and I do not have any affiliation with Particle Designer (even though I really like, use and recommend it for cocos2d projects).